# Issue when the points have the same value

Tags: highcharts

The issue is this: I have a chart type "line" and when all values shown are equal, the scale of min and max becomes in 0 and 1. I need to recalculate the max to avoid this.

Example:

[image]

The chart is dynamic, so I wonder if is possible put a function in the yAxis when the data is updated and recalculate the max for the new data.

Comment: You can simply set `minRange: 0.5`, to avoid this.

Comment: The data is dynamic, perhaps a function to recalculate the range it is more convenient no? because if a value below that range is inserted, it will not be updated right?

Comment: minRange is to set minimum extremes on  axis, but if you want function, then you have events like `setExtremes` and `afterSetExtremes` - there you can try change extremes. OR use Highcharts.wrap() for setting extremes (that requires digging in sources).